# AMD Driver update (one from amd.com)

Tags: drivers, ati, updates

Hi guys what is the BEST way to update driver from AMD.com Right now I am on latest 13.3 Beta 3 and just for future how do I update. On installation tut. you guys saying remove any old drivers before install new one from amd.com. IS this same way updating from 13.3 beta 3 to let's say beta 4 or even 13.3 Gold release ? In other words it's always best to delete everything and re install driver ? Reason I am asking I am not too clear on how to ERASE everything that have to do with amd.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This is how i do it. Works perfekt

```
# eg Upgrade from AMD Catalyst 13.2 beta 2 to 13.2 beta 3
# Go into your Downloads folder (I suppose you have already download the driver)
cd Downloads

# Make the package executable
chmod +x amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.2-beta3-linux-x86.x86_64.run

# Create deb packages for precise (12.04) or quantal (12.10)
sudo sh ./amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.2-beta3-linux-x86.x86_64 --buildpkg Ubuntu/precise

# Force overwrite the older packages with the new ones
sudo dpkg --force-overwrite -i *.deb

# Reboot you PC
If want to unistall them

sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

Comment: few modifications, I would suggest moving the new driver (.run file) into its own directory to avoid any old driver .debs in your downloads folder. Secondly I would also suggest purging the drivers before installing the package (unless this is not needed because of the overwrite? please provide more information on this). If the purge really is part of a separate function (specifically for un-installing the drivers, maybe separate it instead of having it in one code block). Other than that thanks, just followed this and it worked!